# Why does the code inside if condition executes even though it shouldnt using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to execute a patch request to an API only when some condition is true.

Here is my code:

```js
async createItem({params: {
    isItem,
    values,
}} {
    const params: any = {};
    try {
        const {data: item} = await this.post('/${items}/',params);
    };
    itemId = item.id;
    const valuesPromises = values.create.map({variable, value}) => 
        this.post('/api/values/', {
            variable,
            value,
            item: itemId,
         })
      );

      await Promise.all(valuesPromises).then(async () => {
          if (isItem && values.length > 0 ) {
              params.is_item = isItem;
              await this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params);
          )
      });


      return item;
  }
```

The problem is that even if `values.length` is 0 the patch request to the API still happens. I don't want the code inside the if block to execute. I am not sure where the problem is.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: What are the values of isItem & values when you hit your if statement and how are you determining that?

Comment: isItem is a string value which can be either of thesee 'none', 'item1', 'item2'. and if the values is empty array then i dont send isItem to backend (even though it has values 'none', 'item1', 'item2') if the values is not empty array then i have to send the isItem value to backend with a patch.

Comment: Please console.log(values) and see what's the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand how `Promise.all` works. So, if you pass an empty array of promises then it executes the handler immediately (as there are no more promises to wait)
Link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

If you do not want to execute it in this case, you can wrap it with if a condition like that

```
if(valuesPromises.length > 0) {
    await Promise.all(valuesPromises).then(async () => {
      params.is_item = isItem;
      await this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params);
    });
}
```

P.S. from the description I see that there is an issue in your if check as you check for `values.length` instead of `values.create.length` inside the promise.